# Bearer token no funciona 403 php

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Buenas tardes tengan todos, tengo un detalle con curl de bearer token pero al momento de hacer la peticion a la api este me envia un 403 estoy usando ci3 con php 7.4.3

esto es todo lo que eh avanzado pero no tengo resultado alguno

```
protected $curl = 'http://xxxxxxx/';
public function funcion($metodo, $ruta, $parametros = [])
{

    $url = $this->curl . $ruta;
    $token = $_SESSION['api_blazar_token'];
    $api = curl_init();
    $headers = [
        "User-Agent: Example REST API Client",
        "Authorization: Bearer $token",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache"
    ];
    curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
    if ($metodo == 'GET') {
        curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' . http_build_query($parametros));
    } else {
        curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?');
        curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parametros));
    }
    curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($api);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($api, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    //$headerstring = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    //$body = substr($response, $header_size);
    return $response;
}
```

Estos parametros le envio a la funcion

```
$response = $this->webservice->funcion('GET','cursos/marcas');
```

Y este error me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega también el content type a `$headers`, o sea, esto: `'Content-Type: application/json',`. Y, ¿estás seguro de que el token es válido? Dinos también qué versión de PHP estás usando.

Comment: Hola igual intente con content tope y ningún resultado obtuve el tomen si es valido lo probé en la api y funcionó estoy usando php 7.4.3

Comment: Me parece que algunas cosas han cambiado desde PHP 7, intenta poner estas opciones: **`curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BEARER);`** y también: **`curl_setopt($api,CURLOPT_XOAUTH2_BEARER,$token);`**

Comment: Intente con httpheader y funciono intentare con este la verdad soy nuevo usando curl gracias por ayudarme ten un buen dia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La mera en la que solucione este problema fue remplazando el header por

```
$headers = [
        "Authorization: Bearer $token",
       
    ];
 
    curl_setopt($api, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: hola buen da la plataforma me indica que puedo aceptarlo en un transcurso de 8 horas saludos.